# Python wrapper coinbase api errors

Tags: python-3.x, coinbase-api

So I am trying to create a new wallet using the Python wrapper for the coinbase api.

My current code is this:

```
from coinbase.wallet.client import Client

client = Client('API-Key',
                'SECRET',
                api_version='2019-12-30')

# Get your primary coinbase account
primary_account = client.get_primary_account()
address = primary_account.create_address()
print(address)
```

When trying to use the code above, I always get the error:

*coinbase.wallet.error.AuthenticationError: APIError(id=authentication_error): request timestamp expired*

My guess is that the wrapper is not passing the right timestamp.

On the [github page](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-python) for this wrapper, it says that the current build is failing. I don't know how to fix this. The github hasn't had any recent updates. I tried to look at the client file to see if I could fix it myself, but I have had no luck.

Comment: The same error happens with pretty much all calls I try and use. Including

client.get_accounts()

Comment: Why don't you try out other releases? You can use their tags to check it

Comment: Is this using sandbox or the live version?

Comment: @EdekiOkoh the live version. I am using my real api key.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue but, as I've understood from the various contributions, the problem is due to the difference between the local OS time and Coinbase servers time. Besides 30 seconds of epochs difference, coinbase server returns the tedious timestamp expiration error!
I've found python code to update local Windows time based on various ntp servers [ntp_update_time.py (shared by gilmotta)](https://gist.github.com/gilmotta/200dfc135b00b3e97ed79b711de6009a). Launching the ntp_update_time's code before running coinbase client again makes the error disappear and everything work as indicated in Coinbase API references!!!